# Sparql brush for SyntaxHighlighter

Tags: javascript, syntaxhighlighter

I am writing this post to ask about the best way you think it should be done.
I have a task to implement new brush for Gorbachev SyntaxHighlighter. But I don't know sparql at all. After searching I got the idea to port one of the ready highlighter.  I choose one python based. But it is lexer. 
https://github.com/gniezen/n3pygments/tree/master/swlexers
Looking for opinion on the approach and eventually if you can prompt me a better solution. Any feedback is welcome.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will say you have to do the same as syntax highlighter does for other language, 
SPARQL is nothing but a Query Language, with its keywords from [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/) we can identify the keywords that is required to highlight,

For Example Simple Query:

```
SELECT ?title
WHERE
{
  <http://example.org/book/book1> <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/title> ?title .
}
```

Here we need to highlight `SELECT` `?title` that is twice there and `where` with opening and closing braces `{` with `}` , so that should do in this case,

so create list on bases of language keywords and that will help you finish the task :)

I hope this will help..

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to read the language specification. But if you are too lazy for that, you may take a look to other highlighters, such as codemirror: https://github.com/marijnh/CodeMirror/blob/master/mode/sparql/sparql.js